# How to get my laptop to detect SD cards inserted into its built-in card reader?

Tags: sd-card

My laptop has a built-in SD Card reader but it cannot detect one when inserted. Here is the result when I type `lspci` from the terminal:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RS480 Host Bridge (rev 10)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RS480 PCI Bridge
00:06.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RS480 PCI Bridge
00:07.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RS480 PCI Bridge
00:12.0 IDE interface: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 Serial ATA Controller (rev 80)
00:13.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 USB Host Controller (rev 80)
00:13.1 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 USB Host Controller (rev 80)
00:13.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 USB2 Host Controller (rev 80)
00:14.0 SMBus: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 SMBus Controller (rev 83)
00:14.1 IDE interface: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 IDE Controller (rev 80)
00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB4x0 High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 PCI-ISA Bridge (rev 80)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 PCI-PCI Bridge (rev 80)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RS482 [Radeon Xpress 200M]
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 01)
05:04.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): O2 Micro, Inc. Firewire (IEEE 1394) (rev 02)
05:04.2 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Integrated MMC/SD Controller (rev 01)
05:04.3 Mass storage controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Integrated MS/xD Controller (rev 01)
05:09.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT2561/RT61 rev B 802.11g
```

Comment: You should specify your Ubuntu version first and which type od SD card you are using (SD, SDHC, ecc. and how many gigabytes it contains)

Comment: @Candelight : could you post the `dmesg` output after you insert a SD card in the reader.

Comment: Maybe the following link can be applied to this question too, https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035

Comment: @sudodus OP hasn't signed on since Jan 2012. As such unlikely to follow the link you posted. Nonetheless VTC to close as dupe you suggested to remove this question off `unanswered list`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this without your SD card inserted on boot.

*From a post by PseudoPsyche at fedoraforums*

> 1. You must add the following lines to one of the `.conf` files in `etc/modprobe.d` folder. I believe it would be `dist.conf`*
> 2. Do this, by typing the following into konsole/terminal. (substitute gedit with text editor of choice)
>
>    ```
>    sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/dist.conf  
>    alias mmc_core tifm_core  
>    alias mmc_card tifm_sd
>    ```
> 3. Save the file.

***If this is the wrong .conf file, someone please correct me.**

Comment: This has no effect for me.

Comment: The file name doesn't actually matter, but the directory does and it's correct. To avoid issues with packaged and generated files in the same directory, it would help to create a *new* file for this.