# Macbook pro 8,1 ubuntu 12.04 sd card reader doesnt work

Tags: 12.04, sd-card, macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get my laptop to detect SD cards inserted into its built-in card reader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94357/how-to-get-my-laptop-to-detect-sd-cards-inserted-into-its-built-in-card-reader)

THe built in sd card reader on the macbook pro 8,1 (2011, early or mid i think) doesnt work AT ALL.  However i read here.... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/801034 that someone plugged in ethernet and it works. How the hell does that make a difference? There has to be some kind of better workaround? I take my laptop on the go, thats why i bought a LAPTOP. I dont want to be tethered down.  Please help?

Answer (score 1):

on MacBook Pro the wireless and the card reader have the same controller in a integrated chip:

http://www.broadcom.com/products/Ethernet-Controllers-and-Adapters/Enterprise-Client-Controllers/BCM57765

thus, there is a relation between the network and the card reader...

I also have the MacBook Pro 8,1 with Ubuntu 12.10. So far I didn't find any solution. And I don't have ethernet right now to try this one... but I'll try later.

Please post if you find a solution.

Cheers